# What's the difference between mvn archetype:generate and mvn archetype:create

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

any difference between those two?

Comment: While working with maven and referring to the docs, at some places I have come across a message saying `create` is deprecated (can't recall exactly where) while at other places, such as the getting started guide, they have themselves used `create` instead of `generate`. I personally use generate

Comment: Quote from the Archetype plugin *create* goal [documentation page](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-mojo.html): "**This plugin goal has been deprecated**. Please use the generate mojo instead."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`archetype:create` is the old and deprecated form that needed all properties defined upon start, while `archetype:generate` is the newer and more comfortable way. archetype:generate knows about those catalogs where archetypes are listed and can ask you for missing properties/variables.

I guess the reason for introducing a new command was that the new generate was not backward-compatible, so it might have broken existing scripts that rely on it.

Answer (score 6):

Check [the documentation for archetype generate](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html), create has been kept for backwards compatibility:

> For backward compatibility with the Archetype Plugin version 1.0-alpha-7, we kept the old `create` goal which can be called using `mvn archetype:create`.

So create and generate will do the same thing but create has been deprecated so you should use the generate command instead.