# Maven Home in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu, maven-2, m2e

I am trying to find the Maven home or the `$M2_HOME` variable in my machine but I am unable to find it. I am a Maven newbie btw
I am on Ubuntu 12.04 I installed maven using

> sudo apt-get install maven2

Now I am specifically interested in Maven 2 not 3. Now I am using Spring Tool Suite and the m2e plugin that comes along with it uses Maven 3. I went to `Windows->Preferences->Maven->Installation` and tried to add the maven home but cannot find it.

What I tried till now

```
whereis mvn
```

displays

```
/usr/bin/mvn /usr/bin/X11/mvn /usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz
```

None of these are the home variables

```
echo $M2_HOME
```

displays nothing. Simply blank.
How do I make the m2e plugin to pint towards maven2?

Comment: you dont need to set environmental var to work with m2e plugin

Comment: problem is I am getting an error: Could not calculate build plan I am not sure why is it but currently I tried changing the maven home from the 3 that is embedded to the 2 that I installed from apt repository. The maven 2 is giving successful build in the command line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209343/whats-the-difference-between-mvn-archetypegenerate-and-mvn-archetypecreate    I had used the archetype:generate command on Maven2 which might have been a cause for the break

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the answer `/usr/share/maven2`

Answer (score 2):

Maven 3 for example located at /usr/share/maven

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone stumbles upon this. You can use

```
mvn --version
```

to find out. For me it prints  the following first two lines (installed via apt on ubuntu):

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
```